# using select2 in a prestashop module

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, jquery-select2, prestashop-1.6

I would like to use select2.js in a prestashop module that I am customizing.
Every solution I tried gave a blank page each time I tried to initialize selec2 to tell him on how select I want it.

I found one admin page that uses select2 : AdminModulesPositionController.php, but if I copy what's inside it failed.

Is anybody could help me to find the correct way to have a select2 list in my module admin page ?

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT : what I did

1) the module I want to modify uses the AdminController.php, that calls plugins, so I modified it :

```
    $this->addJquery();
    $this->addjQueryPlugin(array('scrollTo', 'alerts', 'chosen', 'autosize', 'fancybox', 'select2' ));
```

.../...

```
$this->addJS(array(
    _PS_JS_DIR_.'admin.js?v='._PS_VERSION_,
    _PS_JS_DIR_.'tools.js?v='._PS_VERSION_,
    _PS_JS_DIR_.'jquery/plugins/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js',
    _PS_JS_DIR_.'jquery/plugins/select2/select2_locale_'.$this->context->language->iso_code.'.js'
));
```

I checked in the debugger and select2 with locale are called by the module page : good

2) I added a class to the select I want to enhance
3) then I tried to initialize select by several ways :
   -like the documentation says in the html part of my module :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').select2();
</script>
```

Blank page for all the shop

-by trying to do the same than AdminModulesPositionController.php / modulePosition.js :

```
var show_modules = $("#show_modules");
        show_modules.select2();
```

same problem.

In fact, I'm a poor developper, so I don't know how prestashop machine work, and I don't find the way to do a simple php thing (I use select2 in my "simple" php website) in this complex system..

Here is the complete function where I try to use select2 :

```
    public function displayinputid($return=0){
   if ($this->psversion()==5 || $this->psversion()==6){
       $verps="";
   } else {
       $verps="14";
   }

      $resultemp= Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM `ps_employee` WHERE id_profile=4');

    //idemploye
    $selectemp="<select name=\"idemp\" id=\"idemp\">";

     $selectemp .= "<option value =\"0\" hidden>Employee</option>";
     foreach ($resultemp as $k) {
     $selectemp .= "<option value=".$k["id_employee"].">".$k["firstname"]." ".$k["lastname"]."</option>" ;
    }

     $selectemp.="</select >";
     if (Shop::getContextShopID() !=0) {
        $resultcustomer = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM `ps_customer` WHERE id_shop='.Shop::getContextShopID().'');

     }
     else {
        $resultcustomer = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('SELECT * FROM `ps_customer`');

     }

    //idcustomer
    $selectCustomer="<select name=\"idcus\" id=\"idcus\" class=\"idcus\">";

      $selectCustomer .= "<option value =\"0\" hidden>Client</option>";
     foreach ($resultcustomer as $k) {
     $selectCustomer .= "<option value=".$k["id_customer"].">".$k["firstname"]." ".$k["lastname"]." - ".$k["company"]."</option>" ;
    }

     $selectCustomer.="</select >";

      //idcustomer
    $selectCustomerdel="<select name=\"delcus\" id=\"delcus\">";
    $selectCustomerdel .= "<option value =\"0\" hidden>Client</option>";       

     foreach ($resultcustomer as $k) {
     $selectCustomerdel .= "<option value=".$k["id_customer"].">".$k["firstname"]." ".$k["lastname"]."</option>" ;
    }

     $selectCustomerdel.="</select >";






      $resultlistcusemp = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->ExecuteS('SELECT  pe.firstname as nomemploi ,
        pe.lastname as nomemploi2 ,
        ps.id_customer as idclient,
        ps.firstname as nomclien ,
        ps.lastname as nomcl2 
        FROM ps_personalsalesmen p
        INNER JOIN ps_customer ps 
        ON p.id_customer=ps.id_customer
        INNER JOIN ps_employee pe 
        ON pe.id_employee  = p.id_employee');

    //idcus
    $listecusemp="<table id=\"example\" class=\"table table-striped table-bordered\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\"> <tr><thead><td style=\"color:green\">Employee</td> <td style=\"color:green\">Customer</td> <td style=\"color:green\">ID Customer</td></tr></thead>";


     foreach ($resultlistcusemp as $k) {
     $listecusemp .= "<tr><td>".$k["nomemploi"]."".$k["nomemploi2"]."</td> <td>".$k["nomclien"]." ".$k['nomcl2'] ." </td><td>".$k['idclient']."</td></tr>" ;
    }

     $listecusemp .="</table>



     ";





    $ret= "
      <style>
                  table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid ;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 400px;
        }
        select {
            width: 288px!important;
            text-align: center!important;
        }
        select:invalid { color: gray; }

    </style>
        <script>
                     $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').DataTable();
        } );

        function linkcustomerbyid(id,msg){


                    document.getElementById(\"linkbyid\").submit();

        }           
    </script>
    <fieldset style = \" width: 800px;\">
        <div align=\"center\" style=\"margin-bottom:20px;\">
        <h3>".$this->l('Link a customer to a employee.')."</h3>
            <form action=\"index.php?tab=personalsalestab$verps&token={$_GET['token']}\" method=\"post\" id=\"linkbyid\" name=\"linkbyid\">

            <strong>".$this->l('Select customer :')."<br/></strong><br>
            ".$selectCustomer."<br/><br/>

            <strong>".$this->l('Select employee:')."<br/></strong><br>
            ".$selectemp."<br/><br/>

            <img src=\"../modules/personalsalesmen/save.png\" onClick=\"linkcustomerbyid(document.getElementById('idcus'),'".$this->l('Are you sure you want link this customer:')." #"."'+document.getElementById('idcus').value+'"." ".$this->l('to this employee: ')." #"."'+document.getElementById('idemp').value+'"."');\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\" >
            <br> <br> <br> <br>
            <strong>".$this->l('Delete all of the linked employees of a customer.')."<br/></strong>
            <br> 

            ".$selectCustomerdel."<br/><br/>

            <img src=\"../modules/personalsalesmen/delete.gif\" onClick=\"linkcustomerbyid(document.getElementById('delcus'),'".$this->l('Are you sure you want delete this customers links:')." #"."'+document.getElementById('delcus').value+'"."');\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\" >            
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <center>
            <h3>List of linked customers/employees .</h3>
           ".$listecusemp."
           </center>
    </fieldset>
    ";

    if ($return==0){
        echo $ret;
    } else {
        return $ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly did you try? Show us your module controller code and how you are initializing select2 in it.

Comment: Well if HTML displays without select2 init, then either move select2 initialization to the end of page or put it inside a `$(document).ready()` function. Though I doubt it will help because your module is a big mess, that is not how you generate pages in Prestashop or in any other kind of MVC environment and because of that your problem could be caused by god knows what. Please read about [Form helper](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperForm+class) and look at other admin controllers files how they generate pages.

Comment: thanks for the advice ! The biggest problem I guess, is that I take a module written by somebody else (and as you said, is a big mess ;-) )

Comment: If the module is not that big/complicated you might want to rewrite it properly as it will help you in the long run. As you see something as trivial as adding select2 component causes problems, who knows what problems will be there if/when you want to modify/upgrade this module. And one more advice regarding your first step: never modify core files. First always use [module hooks](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5) and if that's not possible, use [overriding](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Overriding+default+behaviors).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the admin controller then, add the **select2.js** using the **addJQueryPlugin** in the **setMedia() function**

```
public function setMedia()
{
    parent::setMedia();
    $this->context->controller->addJQueryPlugin('select2');
}
```

In the below example, I have applied select2 on the select field

```
 <select name="country[]" multiple id="country_select">
      <option value="us">US</option>
      <option value="france">France</option>
      <option value="italy">Italy</option>
      <option value="india">India</option>
 </select>
```

Add the below code in the **JS** file to apply **select2**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#country_select').select2({
        placeholder: 'select',
        formatNoMatches: 'no match found',
        allowClear: true
    });
});
```